# How can I find user role based on user id?

Tags: users

There are many user list.
My need is to find out user role based on their user id.

Comment: You need to add more details. For example, do you get that user list from a page, or do you have code that returns you a list of user IDs?

Answer (score 3):

Use user_load() or global $user.

```
global $user;
$account = $user;
$role = $account->roles;// returns user role.
```

or

```
$user = user_load(uid);
$role = $user->roles;//return user role
```

Comment: Assuming the OP has a list of user IDs, this is the worse way to get the roles for those user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a common task on your website you could also use the [administration views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views). With this module you can create and manage user-lists and you can modify the view to your needs, with all the power of views (exposed filters, relationships ecetera):

> Filter all administrative views via AJAX. Perform any kind of
>   bulk/mass operations on items in administrative views. Filter content
>   by title, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary.
>   Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
>   Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.